# Lattice Version of Stone-Weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've been reviewing Stone-Weierstrass theoerem. While reading the wikipedia page I read the following version of the theorem:

Suppose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space with at least two points and $L$ is a lattice in $C(X, \mathbb{R})$. The function $φ ∈ C(X, R)$ belongs to the closure of $L$ if and only if for each pair of distinct points $x$ and $y$ in $X$ and for each $ε > 0$ there exists some  $f  ∈ L$ for which $| f (x) − φ(x)| < ε$ and $| f (y) − φ(y)| < ε$.

While I understand how to prove the forward implication, I'm not sure how to prove the backwards direction.

I assume that there is a $φ ∈ C(X, R)$ such that for each pair of distinct points $x$ and $y$ in $X$ and for each $ε > 0$ there exists some  $f  ∈ L$ for which $| f(x) − φ(x)| < ε$ and $| f(y) − φ(y)| < ε$. To be in the closure of $L$, since $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ is a metric space, I only need to find a sequence of functions that converges to $φ$.

By the hypothesis, for each $ε > 0$ if I fix $x$ and let $y$ vary I can find a collection of functions $\{f_y:y \in X\}$ such that for each $y$, $| f_y(x) − φ(x)| < ε$ and $| f_y(y) − φ(y)| < ε$. I'm not sure how to go about building a sequence of functions that converges to $φ ∈ C(X, R)$.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Generally, when faced with a theorem that encapsulates the work of mathematicians over two centuries, I don't expect that I'll sit down and prove it myself on the spot. The proof can be found in books (search for `Stone Weierstrass theorem lattice`), or on page 2 of [this write-up](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~nikita/MT4111/stone-weierstrass.pdf). As I recall, the proof of S-W in Rudin's PMA book does not use the language of lattices, but the reasoning is there.